# Does introducing an intermediate list might cause performance overhead?

Tags: java, list

```
List<UserData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
List<UserData> dataList1 = dataRepository.findAllByProcessType(ProcessType.OUT);
List<UserData> dataList2 = dataRepository.findAllByProcessType(ProcessType.CORPORATE_OUT);
dataList.addAll(dataList1);
dataList.addAll(dataList2 );
return dataList ;
```

vs

```
List<UserData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.addAll(dataRepository.findAllByProcessType(ProcessType.OUT));
dataList.addAll(dataRepository.findAllByProcessType(ProcessType.CORPORATE_OUT));
return dataList ;
```

does the first implementation will cause any performance overhead? (i.e. more garbage / memory allocation than the second one)

P.S. - Yes, it can be optimised using one round trip to db as mentionted by @Tim. But that's not the answer i am looking for.I am in general want to know whether this type of implementation will cause overhead or not. Because this type of implementation helps debugging.

Comment: I would be surprised if any measured performance difference fell outside the margin of error. In other words, I expect both implementations to have practically the same performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to say no, on the basis that I would be very surprised if the two code blocks produce different bytecode.

The first code does not "introduce an intermediate list".  All it does is create new variables to reference lists that were created by the dataRepository call.  I would expect the compiler to simply optimise those variables out.

Those lists are also created in the second code example, so there's no real difference.

Knowing that the compiler performs these sorts of optimisations frees us as programmers to write code that is well laid-out, clear, and maintainable, whilst still remaining confident that it will perform well.

The other consideration is debugging.  In the first code block, it is easy to set breakpoints on the variable declaration lines, and inspect the values of the variables.  Those simple operations become a pain when code is implemented in the second code block.

Comment: Well, I would say yes. You are adding from 2 lists in the first implementation. Those two intermediate lists will have to be garbage collected. I guess that would cause overhead. What I said above is purely speculation thought, and are not backed by any measurements.

Comment: @DogaOruc But the calls to `findAllByProcessType` will cause those two lists to be created and returned, regardless of them being stored in variables, which means they'll need to be garbage collected in both implementations.

Comment: But the lists are created, and will have to be garbage collected, anyway.  The only difference is that variables are referring to them    @Slaw Thanks - you beat my slow typing !  :)

Comment: But that still uses 2 more pointers, isn't it? Java doesn't actually return the lists, it returns the pointers to those lists though. I'm confused. You might be right. Does anyone want to benchmark the two implementations?

Comment: @DogaOruc The references, assuming we're inside a method, are stored on the stack; specifically, in the method's stack _frame_. When the thread exits the method the stack frame is gone/destroyed. However, the actual lists themselves will be stored in the heap regardless, meaning they'll still have to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

As the `addAll()` method should just be referencing the same data, both of your versions should perform about the same.  But, the *best* thing to do here is to avoid the two unnecessary roundtrips to your database, and just use a single query:

```
List<ProcessType> types = Arrays.asList(ProcessType.OUT, ProcessType.CORPORATE_OUT);
List<UserData> dataList = findAllByProcessTypeIn(types);
```

Comment: This is what I would do, not because of performance reasons but because I despise intermediate variables that don't get used anywhere else other than the line below their declaration.